# inject user data in Symfony, FOS loginAction

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony

I'm writing a Symfony 3.0 application and I have the following situation:

- The system provides different login and register pages (one for each subsite)
- A user can have the same username to login on different subsites but accounts are managed separately.

My idea was to save the subsite domain's unique name in the username field with `@` notation, example: 
User `a.ndrew` can access both `domain1` and `domain2` with the same username but the system stores 2 different accounts with usernames `a.ndrew@domain1` and `a.ndrew@domain2`.
I handle this automatically by overwriting `RegistrationController` actions and it works fine during registration but now i'm trying to automatically push "@domain" data in the username at login with no luck. I'm overwriting `loginAction` but I don't understand how to push data in the username.

EDIT (tnx @malcom)
Here is my `loginAction` called `companyUserLoginAction` it simply checks if `companyName` exists and redirect to FOS `loginAction`, I'd like to be able to add `@companyName` at the end of the username provided by user in the login form but I don't understand where this information is handled by the controller:
`

```
/**
 * @Route("/{companyName}/login")
 */
public function companyUserLoginAction(Request $request, $companyName)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $company = $em->getRepository('CompanyBundle:Company')->findOneBy(array('name' => $companyName));
    if ($company == null)
    {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    return $this->loginAction($request);

}

/**
 *Default FOS loginAction
 */
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{


    /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
    $session = $request->getSession();


    if (class_exists('\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security')) {
        $authErrorKey = Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
        $lastUsernameKey = Security::LAST_USERNAME;
    } else {
        // BC for SF < 2.6
        $authErrorKey = SecurityContextInterface::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR;
        $lastUsernameKey = SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME;
    }

    // get the error if any (works with forward and redirect -- see below)
    if ($request->attributes->has($authErrorKey)) {
        $error = $request->attributes->get($authErrorKey);
    } elseif (null !== $session && $session->has($authErrorKey)) {
        $error = $session->get($authErrorKey);
        $session->remove($authErrorKey);
    } else {
        $error = null;
    }

    if (!$error instanceof AuthenticationException) {
        $error = null; // The value does not come from the security component.
    }

    // last username entered by the user
    $lastUsername = (null === $session) ? '' : $session->get($lastUsernameKey);

    if ($this->has('security.csrf.token_manager')) {
        $csrfToken = $this->get('security.csrf.token_manager')->getToken('authenticate')->getValue();
    } else {
        // BC for SF < 2.4
        $csrfToken = $this->has('form.csrf_provider')
            ? $this->get('form.csrf_provider')->generateCsrfToken('authenticate')
            : null;
    }

    return $this->renderLogin(array(
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error,
        'csrf_token' => $csrfToken,
    ));
}
```

}
`

Comment: Do you have two domains point to the same Symfony app, or do you have two subdomains (or one main domain and one subdomain) on the same Symfony app, or you have two domains with two different Symfony apps? Or any other combination just let us know and give more informations (with code you already try).

Comment: tnx edited.
I can have n different subsites with their personal login and register page, the symfony app is the same for all.

Comment: IMO you should have one basic user with `username` and `passwrd`, and extend that user class on different hosts. You can have multiple firewalls based on host http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/firewall_restriction.html#restricting-by-host